# Apache Camel: How do I do a simple modification on files in one directory, then store the output in another directory?

Tags: file, routes, apache-camel

Seems simple, but I can't get it working.  What I want to do is take any files that are placed in the "from" path, modify their contents, and place the modified file in the "to" path (with a .txt extension).  Here's what I have:

```
this.context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
    public void configure() {
        from( "file:" + getFromPath() + getOptions() )
        .to( "file:" + getToPath() + "?fileName=${file:name.noext}.txt")
        .process(new Processor() {
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                String name = (String) exchange.getIn().getHeader("CamelFileName");
                File body = exchange.getIn().getBody(File.class);
                String parsedText = modifyFile(body);
                exchange.getOut().setBody(parsedText);
            }
         })
     ;}
  });
```

The output file is getting created, but the contents are exactly the same as the input file. I.e, the file is not getting modified.  I confirmed that the "modifyFile" method is returning what I want it to, but can't get it to write those contents to the output ("to") path.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6):

If you want to modify the file content, you need to put the processor between the "from" and "to" endpoints.

Comment: Yeah it should be: from -> process -> to